# Сумма значений в столбце за определе нный срок MySql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо вывести суммарное кол-во робуксов и за определенную дату например 02.13.2020 таблица buyers

Comment: inc SELECT SUM( `имя_поля_значения_которог_нужно_сложить` ) FROM `имя_таблицы` WHERE `поле даты` = дата

Comment: @denis640Kb  ```$total_robux = mysqli_query("SELECT SUM(robux) FROM buyers WHERE date = 02.13.2020");?```

Comment: Всё верно, только надо экранировать названия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT SUM(`название_поля`) FROM `название_таблицы` WHERE `колонка_даты` = "2020-12-14"');
```

Если дата в базе хранится в том формате, в котором мы привыкли видеть (14.12.2020), то тогда так:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT SUM(`название_поля`) FROM `название_таблицы` WHERE `колонка_даты` = "14.12.2020"');
```

но в таком случае я бы настоятельно рекомендовал вам поменять формат хранения дат у вас в базе, иначе в будущем могут быть сложности с выборкой по дате.

Чтобы вывести результат через `echo`, делаете так:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $result['SUM(название_поля)'];
```

Comment: = ничего не выводит через echo

Comment: @Sotrydnikinc. а оно и не должно выводить ничего. Чтобы вывело, следует еще сделать `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, а затем только через `echo` выводить: `$result['SUM(название_поля)']`

Comment: @Sotrydnikinc. дополнил ответ. Можете перечитать.

Comment: ```$query = mysqli_query($result, 'SELECT SUM(`robux`) FROM `buyers` WHERE `date` = "02.13.20"');
    $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo $res['SUM(robux)'];``` так?

Comment: @Sotrydnikinc. Да, только где `$result` должен быть объект подключения к MySQL-серверу. Если у вас он так и называется, то этот код должен работать.

Comment: @Mmh1 Вы же просто скопировали комментарий и добавили ковычки ))) Как не стыдно....

Comment: коннект к базе через $result, но ничего не происходит, ничего не выводится

Comment: Все, получилось echo $res['SUM(robux)'] добавил ковычки. итог - ```echo $res['SUM(`robux`)']```

Comment: @Denis640Kb Я ничего не копировал. Как вы себе представляете этот код, написанный по-другому? Тут обычный запрос из базы и вывод. Да и тем более вы не указали объект на коннект к базе, а так же не рассказали о `mysqli_fetch_assoc` и не рассказали про правильное хранение дат.

Comment: @Mmh1 Такие вещи не пишут в ответ. Стыд и позор Вам.

Comment: @Sotrydnikinc. если мой ответ помог, то выберите его лучшим.

Answer (score 0):

$query = mysqli_query($result, 'SELECT SUM(`robux`) FROM `buyers` WHERE `date` = "02.13.20"'); 
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); echo 
$res['SUM(`robux`)'];